# How to post a Form data from Client side to server using RestTemplate?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jsp

For client side i used tomcat 8080 port and for server side i used tomcat 8081 port. I just tried to post Form data to server side using RestTemplate. Is there is any specific way to doing this?

And i tried to do this as follows,

```
   { @RequestMapping(value="/addBook")
   public String addBook(Book book){
    
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

    ResponseEntity<Book> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(
              "http://localhost:8081/api/addbook", book, Book.class);                
    System.out.println(response.getBody());
    return "Home";}
```

this is my form,

```
        <h1>Form</h1>
        <form action="addBook">
            <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            <input type="text" name="author"><br>
             <input type="text" name="stock"><br>
             <input type="submit" ><br>
        </form>
```

And this is my Book class,

```
package com.example.libraryfrontend.entity;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Book {
private String name;
private String author;
private Integer stock;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public Integer getStock() {
    return stock;
}

public void setStock(Integer stock) {
    this.stock = stock;
}}
```

and this is error i faced,

```
> Error while extracting response for type [class com.example.libraryfrontend.entity.Book] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'Book': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Book': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false') at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 6]
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class com.example.libraryfrontend.entity.Book] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'Book': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Book': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')...
```

Can anyone help me for this or is there any special way to send form data to saver side?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? You are calling your /addBook endpoint from within /addBook endpoint? Also, your form should know that fields that you have bound belong to Book class.I see that missing as well.

Comment: i am triyng to send client Form data to server side 'http://localhost:8081/api/addbook' endpoint. My client side tomcat port number is 8080 and server side port number is 8081. When i click submit button, data will send to database but at same time above mention error appears.

Comment: check json you are sending, according to the error, there is some excess "Book:" term there. Think it is `Book: {data here}` instead of `{data here}`

Comment: @TEXHIK when i print "book" object it shows as **com.example.libraryfrontend.entity.Book@7e65aa36**. How i convert this to JSON. However when i submitted the Form data it stored in DB it means that Form data sent to server side, but also appears that above mention error.